# VirtualBox: "Move" guest window becomes grayed out after switching monitors // how to fix (other than rebooting the guest)?

Tags: virtualbox, external-monitor, usb-c

With a **Ubuntu host**, and **Windows guest** (all up-to-date with the latest versions as per 15 Dec 2023; i.e., Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, VirtualBox 7.0.12 r159484 (Qt5.15.3), and Windows 10), I am reproducibly experiencing what appears to be buggy behaviour:

In my currently preferred setup, I'm using **half of the screen** for the (Windows) guest, and the half for the (Ubuntu) host, and that works svelte.

However, I'm working on a laptop, connected to various modern monitors via USB-C (but only one monitor at a time; I generally prefer the "Single Display"-option). I can't yet exactly pinpoint when the buggy behaviour starts, but the bottom line is, after some **suspends**, some **external monitor re-connects**, possibly some **laptop-monitor** usage, that the **guest window can no longer be moved** (into the desired position of filling half the screen, again), with the corresponding **option** simply **grayed out**, cf. screenshot:

[image: "Move" grayed out for guest window]

The only way to "fix" it (so that none of the options are grayed out) seems to be to **reboot the guest**. Sub-ideal, but ok.

Again, I assume this is a bug, but maybe it isn't and can be resolved without rebooting the guest?

---

PS: From the VirtualBox menu, I sometimes use/toggle the `View > Auto-resize Guest Display` entry (but that doesn't do the trick here), cf.

[image: "View" menu of VirtualBox guest window]